# Provision Template to Main SharePoint Site

Tags: sharepoint-online, online

Is it possible to provision a template from https://lookbook.microsoft.com/ to your main https://domain.sharepoint.com site instead of /sites or /teams?

We don't currently use our default site and set it up to redirect to another site. I want to use it as the main site, so I am looking to somehow provision these templates or even somehow just create a new site with all the same web parts etc that these allow. Maybe I have to some how upgrade the site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default root site can be swapped for a different site in your SharePoint Online tenant. Therefore you could create the site using the look book and then swap the default root site for the newly created site using [the guidance Microsoft have provided](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/modern-root-site#replace-your-root-site).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you could replace the root site template using site design you need via look book UI or Powershell:

Invoke-SPOSiteDesign

Refer to the similar issue for more information:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/msonline/en-US/c8023091-f3c1-46fa-9e67-7d4384540aca/how-do-i-make-a-site-design-available-to-my-other-site-collections?forum=onlineservicessharepoint